# Handle all not handled exceptions

Tags: java, exception

Is it possible to handle (a simple log writing) all not handled exceptions?

In more details, I need to log any exception that occurs anywhere in the code, log the exception and then *continue* (which might results into more exceptions obviously!).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "continue"? AFAIK, once an exception is propagated up the calling stack there is no way to "continue" with whatever your code was doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [Default Uncaught Exception Handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) to catch any unhanded exceptions.

Is is also possible to set a specific handler per thread or thread group.

Answer (score 1):

You could use AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming) for this. Specifically, you could create an aspect that logs all exceptions.

If you are using spring, you can use the [AfterThrowing Advice Annotation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/aop.html) for this.

Answer (score 0):

here's a piece of code that could help you :

```
public class MyDefaultExceptionHandler extends DefaultExceptionHandler
  {

  private UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH;

  public MyDefaultExceptionHandler() 
    {
    this.defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    }

  @Override
  public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) 
    {
    //print anything you wish about the Throwable e :getStackTrace(), getCause(), getClass()...
    defaultUEH.uncaughtException(t, e); //this will call the default handling of the exception (crash...)
    }
  }
… 
//in the main app:
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyDefaultExceptionHandler());
```